# iOS Messages not repeating alert notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications, settings

I'm using an iPhone 11 on iOS `13.0`.

When I receive a text message, my iPhone doesn't repeat the notification alert, despite the `Repeat Alerts` option being set to `Once`.

These are my configurations under `Settings` > `Notifications` > `Messages`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210393#132

iOS update 13.2 fixes this issue.

Comment: This has fixed the problem. Thanks!